# Procedures declaration

Tags: vhdl

I would like to know if there are any functional differences between the following procedure declaration :

```
procedure spi_write_bus
(
spi_data_mosi       : in DATA_BURST;
spi_data_miso       : in DATA_BURST;
spi_data_lenght     : in natural;

signal spi_mosi     : out std_logic;
signal spi_miso     : out std_logic;
signal spi_clk_en   : out std_logic;
signal spi_cs       : out std_logic;
signal spi_clk_i    : in std_logic  
);


procedure spi_write_bus
(
signal spi_data_mosi        : in DATA_BURST;
signal spi_data_miso        : in DATA_BURST;
signal spi_data_lenght      : in natural;

signal spi_mosi     : out std_logic;
signal spi_miso     : out std_logic;
signal spi_clk_en   : out std_logic;
signal spi_cs       : out std_logic;
signal spi_clk_i    : in std_logic  
);
```

I've tryed to find infos, but maybe I don't know where I can get that. Thanks for any reply

Comment: Their signatures are different. With no class declared for the first three formals of first spi_write_bus the default class is variable while the second one's first three formals are class signal.  What's 'infos'?

Comment: "info name" is a Unix command like "man name" providing information on <name>. The VHDL LRM might not be available in "info" form on the OP's machine...

Answer (score 1):

The VHDL-2008 standard describes this in "4.2.2.1 Formal parameter lists":

> For those parameters with modes, the only modes that are allowed for formal parameters of a procedure are
>   in, inout, and out. If the mode is in and no object class is explicitly specified, constant is assumed. If the
>   mode is inout or out, and no object class is explicitly specified, variable is assumed.

Since the mode of `spi_data_mosi` is `in`, then in first case with no explicit object class `constant` class is assumed, while in the second case the class is explicitly give to `signal`.

The VHDL-2008 describes later in "4.2.2.1 Formal parameter lists";

> In a subprogram call, the actual designator (see 6.5.7.1) associated with a formal parameter of class signal shall be a name denoting a signal. The actual designator associated with a formal of class variable shall be a
>   name denoting a variable. The actual designator associated with a formal of class constant shall be an expression.

This also gives the background for Brian Drummonds comment, since parameters of class `signal` or `variable` requires a formal of the same class, where a parameters of class `constant` just requires an expression, which can be created using literals, signals, and variables.

Comment: Practically, this meant you can pass literals '0', '1' to the first form of the procedure, `spi_write_bus('0', '1', 8, ...);` but the compiler will reject the same call to the second procedure because the literal '0' is not a signal.